# Backbone retrieving data multiple times

Tags: backbone.js, firebase

When I console.log the following code , I noticed that the collection values are retrieved double the time. For example, if there are 2 records saved, then it is being fetched 4 times, for 3 records, it is fetched 9 times. Is this related to zombie views? I thought they were fixed with introduction of this.listenTo.

```
render: function() {
        console.log("inside render");
        var self = this;
        this.model_date = $("#date").val();
        this.dateUrl = "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/" + this.model_date.replace(/\//g, '');
        //create an instance of the collection constructor FoodCollection with the current date
        this.foodCollection = new app.FoodCollection([], { url: this.dateUrl });
        this.listenTo(this.foodCollection, 'add', this.render);
        this.$list.html('');

        //this part is executed multiple times based on the number of records saved.

        this.foodCollection.each(function(food) {
            console.log("iterating over foodCollection");
            var view = new app.FoodRecords({ model: food });
            self.$list.append(view.render().el);
        });
    },

    //called when an item is added and the add-food button is clicked
    addFood: function() {
        console.log("inside addFood");
        if (this.$input.val() == '') {
            return;
        };
        this.foodCollection.create(this.newAttributes());
        this.$input.val('');

    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem is that you have a listener that invokes `render` inside `render` method itself. So every time render is called, new listeners are getting added, increasing the number of time's it'll get called the next time something is added to collection.

You should make sure listeners are added only once. Usually this is done inside the `initialize` callback.

The next problem is with your entire logic. Every time you invoke render you're creating an empty collection?. Step through the code and see what your code is actually doing compared to what you intend to do. If you avoid emptying the collection, then you really want to iterate over the collection and create a new view for all existing models when a new model is added? I don't think so.

Your code should be something like this:

- Fetch collection.
- After fetch render the collection view by iterating over the collection and rendering the item view for each model and appending to collection view.
- When new model is added, render an item view and append to collection. No iteration, no resetting and stuff.

How to do each of those steps have been posted on the internet hundreds of times, so I'm not writing it again.